# Angular HttpClient: If get() fails, then execute a post()

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an HttpClient injected into a service. I have a BehaviorSubject set up to track changes to that value. I am running a mock db with json-server. My service is able to execute the get() correctly when I give it something that exists, but if I give it something that doesn't exist it will give a 404. I want it to execute a post().

For a real world explanation: the user has a calendar with a daily log for each day. If they select a day where a log exists, it will get() it. But if they select a day where one does not exist, the service should post() a blank one on the server. Going back to that day will get() the blank one created earlier.

This is what I have so far:

```
getCurrentDay(id: string) {
    this.http.get<DailyLog>(this.daysUrl + "/" + id).subscribe(data => {
      this._currentDailyLog.next(Object.assign({}, data));
    },
      error => {
        return console.log('Could not load daily log');
      }
    )
  }
```

**For future searchers, here is the answer I got with help from @Poul Krujit. I had to change 2 things from his suggestion: the url for the post cannot contain the /id like the get() and you need to give the object as the 2nd parameter in the post().**

```
  getCurrentDay(id: string) {
    const url = `${this.daysUrl}/${id}`;

    this.http.get<DailyLog>(url).pipe(
      catchError(error =>
        error.status === 404
          ? this.http.post<DailyLog>(this.daysUrl, { "id": id, })
          : throwError(error)
      )
    ).subscribe({
      next: (data) => this._currentDailyLog.next({ ...data }),
      error: (error) => console.log('Could not load daily log:', error)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your title says `post()` but the body says `put()`. Note that you don't need to put the tag in the title either. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: Does `put` return the instance or do you need to call the service again?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Fixed the post/put thing. Though its clear in my description I'm trying to add a new log (because it doesn't exist).

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Sorry, fixed the put/post issue. I want to post() a new log that does not exist onto the server. Thats what I'm trying to fix: the get() returns 404 doesn't exist. So I want to create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `catchError` operator:

```
getCurrentDay(id: string) {
  const url = `${this.daysUrl}/${id}`;

  this.http.get<DailyLog>(url).pipe(
    catchError((error) => error.status === 404 
      ? this.http.post<DailyLog>(url)
      : throwError(error)
    )
  ).subscribe({
    next: (data) => this._currentDailyLog.next({ ...data })),
    error: (error) => console.log('Could not load daily log:', error)
  });
}
```

Comment: This was perfect, just had to change a few logic things, going to edit my post to reflect what actually worked. (the post can't have the id added, just the base url. The post also needs the object added as the 2nd parameter).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can be shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you should not subscribe to an Observable within a service. This makes the data (or error) inaccessible by the caller. Instead of subscribing, you should use operators and return an Observable.

Let's refactor your service

```js
export class SomeService {

  getCurrentDay(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<DailyLog>(this.daysUrl + "/" + id)
               .pipe(
                   /** catchError will be called if an exception is thrown
                   /*  and it expects you to return another Observable
                   /*  which is a great place to make another call
                    *  I assume post method will return newly created instance
                    */                   
                   catchError(err => this.http.post<DailyLog>(this.daysUrl + "/" + id)),
                   // also if you need to do some stuff within your service, you can use tap
                   tap(data => this._currentDailyLog.next(data))
                );
  }

}
```

What the method above does is to try to retrive the data, if an error occures it will call `post` api and return the result of `post`. Also, update the `BehaviorSubject` along the way.

**NOTE:** Since the service does not subscribe anymore, caller of this method has to subscribe to make everything run (Observables are lazy by default and do not execute until subscribed)

Comment: The reason I subscribed in the service is I have a BehaviorSubject in the service. Doesn't this method not update that Subject if the get() succeeds?

Comment: If the caller subscribes, it indeed updates `Subject` within `tap` operator.